# Invalid property 'defaultCountLimit' of bean class [org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate]

Tags: java, spring, spring-ldap

Im getting the following exception while trying to configure the LDAPTemplate on Spring -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapTemplate': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'defaultCountLimit' of bean class [org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate]: Bean property 'defaultCountLimit' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

My configuration is -

```
<ldap:context-source 
        id="contextSource"
        url="myurl"
        base="mybase"
        username="myuser"
        password="mypassword"
        referral="follow"
/>

<ldap:ldap-template id="ldapTemplate" context-source-ref="contextSource" />
```

Ive checked the config and it is working fine when i dont work through the spring context -

```
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrl("myurl");
    contextSource.setBase("mybase");
    contextSource.setUserDn("myuser");
    contextSource.setPassword("mypassword");
    contextSource.setReferral("follow");
    contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

    LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
    ldapTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
```

I cannot see where the countlimit is being set to cause this issue. Ive also tried top set the count limit through ldap-template.

Versions -

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-ldap</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
  <classifier>all</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to a dependency version mismatch. Make sure that you only refer to the correct maven artefacts. For the basic case all you need is spring-ldap-core:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The `spring-ldap` dependency you listed is legacy and should not be included.

Comment: Yeah - there was an old ldap lib getting imported by another part of the project that I had overlooked - thanks